# How to make an http request return it's response inside a route

Tags: node.js, express, http

I have a route that I want to take the data given to it and send it in an http request and return the response in my route. What I have done is that I have this call function that sends the http request and returns the response

```
async function call() {
    axios
    .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      title: "foo",
      body: "bar",
      userId: 1,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return { answer: 30 };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

I tried to call it in the route but it doesn't wait for the http request to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get a caller of `call()` to be able wait for your axios results, then you need to do two things:

1. You need to return a promise from `axios.post()`
2. Your caller needs to either use `.then()` or `await` on that returned promise.
3. Don't eat errors in your `.catch()`.  If you `.catch()` just so you can log and still want the reject returned to the caller, you have to rethrow the error.  In this case, it appears that the caller should catch and log the error.

Here's the code to do those things:

```
function call() {
    return axios.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      title: "foo",
      body: "bar",
      userId: 1,
    }).then((res) => {
      return { answer: 30 };
    });
}

call().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Also, there was no reason to use `async` here.  `async` has no magic powers to know when an asynchronous operation inside the function is done.  You still have to return a promise or use `await` on every promise.  In this case, since you weren't using `await`, there is no reason to use `async` so I removed it as you can just return the one promise you have.

Answer (score 0):

I like @jfriend00's answer better, but here is one using async/await

```
async function over() {
  async function call() {
    return await axios
      .post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        title: 'foo',
        body: 'bar',
        userId: 1,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        return { answer: 30 };
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  let result = await call();
  console.log(result);
}

over();
```

Comment: There is no point to the `await` in `return await axios.post()`.  It's just extra overhead.